# azure devops checkout multiple repositories

Tags: azure-devops

I want to checkout multiple repositories.
I have 2 repositories repoA and repoB.

Each repo has 3 branches : dev, staging and main.
Obviously, when repoA is built from main, I want repoB to be checkedout from main.
This can be triggered by a change or a pull request.

The problem with the yaml below is that it sees the branchName variable as duplicate: I want to extract the branchname that triggered repoA in order to checkout repoB in the same branch.

```html
trigger:
  - dev 
  - staging
  - main

pr:
  - dev
  - staging
  - main
  
pool:
  name: "Azure Pipelines"
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/') }}:
    branchName: $[ replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') ]
    
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/') }}:
    branchName: $[ replace(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') ]
        
steps:
- checkout: Self
- checkout: git://ProjectName/repoB@$(branchName)
  path: s/repoB
```

Comment: did you try to use a unique name for the variable that stores the branch name of repoA ?

Comment: Your pipeline works just fine, I wasn't able to reproduce any issue. if you are worried about the warning you can choose to ignore it or use `{{ elseif }}` / `{{ else }}` instead of the second `if`